# Is it possible to make a link in HTML execute two scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a link in html to execute two different javascript scripts. I could probably rewrite both scripts into one, but I have a feeling this problem is going to come up again with a more complex script and this isn't going to be an option.

I am trying to get a link to both hide and show a `<div>` and change the link's text from "hide" to "show" and vice versa.

These are some of my code snippets:

**Javascript**

```
function hide(object)
{
if (object.style.display=="block")
    object.style.display="none"
else
    object.style.display="block"
}

function menuChange(object)
{
if (object.innerHTML=="hide")
    object.innerHTML="show"
else
    object.innerHTML="hide"
}
```

I want both of these to execute when

```
<a id="button">hide</a>
```

is pressed.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to combining both scripts?

Comment: Like `onclick="hide(this);menuchange(this);"` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a 3rd function:

```
function doBoth(object) {
  hide(object);
  menuChange(object);
}
```

I usually make one function per element or group of element, and call it `buttonOnClick()`, which only calls one or more functions that do their job.

Comment: It's a good thing to separate the concept of functions that do a specific task, from the functions that are just event handlers. +1.

Comment: This works. So then, is it impossible to make two `href` attributes in a link, or something similar?

Comment: @Snip3r yes. you can't have duplicate attributes (well, you can, but one of them will be ignored). html5 has a `source` tag that allows multiple sources (like for video streams), but doesn't sound like that will help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Stenci's option would work well in your case. You could also accept an optional parameter in the first function and then do a conditional operation on this parameter to call the second function from within the first function.

Comment: you could, i guess, but there's no good reason to do that for this example